# Photo Special Effects Software

Tags: software-recommendation, effects, photo-management

I would like to know about a software for creating special effects on photos just like on http://avatar.pho.to/ . it is not necessary that it should have all effects. you may even recommend more than one .It can be both free and non-free

Answer (score 0):

You can create animated gifs using GIMP. It's not easy to replicate those effects, though. It will take lots of experience and practice.